# Razor Ternary Operator to render Html Tags (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, rendering, ternary-operator

I'm trying to apply a responsive design to my asp.net mvc 4 application. I want to loop my model and render 3 items per line. Each line shall be wrapped in a div. The result should look something like this:

```
<div class='ResponsiveWrapper'>
    <div>
        <!-- item1 -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- item2 -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- item3 -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class='ResponsiveWrapper'>
    <div>
        <!-- item4 -->
    ...
```

In order to do so, I'm trying to use ternary operators:

```
@{ var i = 0; }
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    @Html.Raw(i == 0 ? Html.Encode("<div class='section group'>") : "")

    <div>
        //Responsive Content comes here
    </div>

    @Html.Raw(i == 2 ? Html.Encode("</div>") : "")

    @(i<3 ? i++ : i=0)
}
```

Now I have 2 Problems:

1. The HTML Tags which the ternary operators should render come in plain text. I tried different combinations of `@Html.Raw` and `@Html.Encode` and Strings, but it nothing worked for me
2. It seems like the last Ternary Operator renders the current value of the variable `i`. How can I prevent this?

**Additional information/Code explanation**

The logic already works fine:

- The `i` Variable is the count variable.
- `If i = 0` I first render the start `<div>` tag of the wrapper and than I render the current `model.item`
- `If i = 1` I only render the current `model.item`
- `If i = 2` I first render the current `model.item` and than the `</div>` end tag

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Both, ***MajoB***'s and ***Chris Pratt***'s approaches basically work. Since ***MajoB***'s solution was more detailed, I went with that one.
However, I had to make some modifications in order to get it to work:

1. At the Controller, I had to assure, that a IList is being returned, rather than a IEnumberable

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       return View(db.leModel.ToList());
   }
   ```
2. At the View, I had to change the signature (like 1., IList instead of IEnumerable)

   ```
   @model IList<leProject.Models.leModel>
   ```
3. Various modifications at the razor code (otherwise it would throw me exceptions)

Final Code:

```
<div class="ResponsiveWrapper">
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    // the lambda expression modelItem => item.leProperty did not work for some reason. So I had to replace the item with Model[i], which means, the following line is not neccessary
    { var item = Model[i]; }

    <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].leProperty)
    </div>

    if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0 || i == (Model.Count - 1))
    {
        @:</div> 
        if (Model.Count + 1 - i >= 3)
        {
            @:<div class="ResponsiveWrapper">
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you guys :)

Comment: `@(stuff)` tells Razor to print the output. try `@{stuff}` instead :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution without the wrapper div:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
   @{ var item = Model[i]; }      

   <div style="float:left;">
       <!-- item1 -->
   </div>

   @if((i+1) % 3 == 0)
   {
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   }
}
```

Solution with wrapper:

```
<div class="ResponsiveWrapper">
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
   @{ var item = Model[i]; }           


   <div>
       <!-- item1 -->
   </div>

   @if((i+1) % 3 == 0 || i == (Model.Count-1)) // in case you have for example 7 items in your list
   {
    @:</div> <!-- end ResponsiveWrapper -->
    @if (i != Model.Count-1)
    {
    @:<div class='ResponsiveWrapper'>
    }
   }      
}
```

Comment: since my Model is a IEnumerable I get an exception "cannot apply indexing with to an expression of type ...ienumerable"
how can I fix that?

Comment: You can change your model to list Model.ToList() or use the foreach approach from your question.

Comment: had to make a few modification, in order to get it to work. I'll update my questions with the tasks I did

Answer (score 2):

Here's the usual way to handle this:

```
<div class="ResponsiveWrapper">
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <div>
        <!-- item -->
    </div>

    @if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
    {
        @:</div><div class="ResponsiveWrapper">
    }
}
</div>
```

Every third item, the wrapper div is closed and opened again. The `@:` prevents Razor from trying to parse this line, so it doesn't throw erroneous syntax errors.